# Sharepoint 2019 unable to install patch

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation

This is a SharePoint 2019 environment, The environment is up and running when checked the health analyzer found the below error:

> Product / patch installation or server upgrade required

Tried to install the latest patch on all the servers and ran the `psconfig` but getting the below message. It says that  SharePoint Server 2016 is missing in all the servers. Not sure why it says SharePoint Server **2016** missing in SharePoint Server **2019**.
[image]

Adding requested screenshot same for all four servers
[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the following page: CentralAdministration -> Upgrade and Migration -> Check product and patch installation status.

Comment: As requested added the screenshot

Answer (score 3):

This is not normal behavior of SharePoint 2019. I see two possible fails on this machine:

- SharePoint Server 2016 was previously installed. You might check if something from SP2016 is left in `appwiz.cpl`. If this is the case: Reinstall SharePoint 2019 on a different machine. SharePoint does not support any kind of InPlace-Upgrade
- A SharePoint 2016 update was accidentally installed. You can check in `appwiz.cpl` -> View installed Updates -> Check if a SP2016 update was installed. You might try to uninstall it. **But check for a working backup first!**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said the client has installed the 2016 and uninstalled and again installed the 2019. some of the reference of 2016 is blocking the patch. is there any way to do a clean uninstall of the 2016 environment?

Comment: Don't try that. Install SharePoint 2019 on a fresh machine with languagepacks and servicepacks, join it to the existing farm, apply custom configuration and retire the existing server.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you @Imran